# Is it possible to use IF ELSE in a MYSQL AND "clause"

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

My example below "obviously" doesn't work ::: Is there a way I can get the **IF ELSE** or something similar to work ::: I have several PHP variables, based on these variables I'd like to change the AND "clause" in this query, without having to create several queries and using PHP if statements to use the correct query block :::

```
$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
          FROM $wpdb->posts 
          INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
          WHERE 1=1 
          AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'cars' 
          AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') 

          IF ( $drive )
          AND ( ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_year' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$year')
          ELSEIF ( $fuel  )
          AND ( ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel')
          ENDIF

          AND ( ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel') )
          GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID 
          ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date 
          DESC LIMIT 0, 99";
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, no real answer is possible. Maybe take a look at a) conditionals inside mysql and b) a more dynamic way to define your query inside php, for example by using the sprintf statement. Even better (on the php side) would anyway to use PDO and prepared queries instead of such static query string.

Comment: You can include `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$p="";
$q="";
if( empty($drive) ){
    $p=" AND ( ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_year' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$year')";
    }else{
        if( empty($fuel)  ){
            $q=" AND ( ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel')";
        }
    }

$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
    WHERE 1=1 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'cars' 
    AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') 
    ".$p.$q."
    AND ( ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel') )
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID 
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date 
    DESC LIMIT 0, 99";
```

Comment: THX for your help, was not exactly what I was hoping for but at least it works and I was able to complete my script :::

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if`

or you can use `case when` which consists of `then, else end` within MYSQL.

- [reference:](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/case-operator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Set your local variables on the basis of your PHP conditions and then use them(local variable ) to prepare sql query ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
      FROM $wpdb->posts 
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
      WHERE 1=1 
      AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'cars' 
      AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') 
      AND CASE WHEN $drive THEN $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_year' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$year'
               WHEN $fuel THEN $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel'
               ELSE 1 = 1 END
      AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel'
      GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID 
      ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date 
      DESC LIMIT 0, 99";
```

Comment: I'm getting this error ::: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CH' at line 8

Comment: What is the value of `$drive` and `$fuel`?

Comment: Drive would be eg. "auto" and fuel "petrol"

Comment: Aaa, that's not columns of table? OK, then what does this `IF ( $drive )` mean?

Comment: No, It would actually be a session variable with value "manual, auto etc.  ::: If $drive is set ( has  a value ) I would like to run the appropriate "THEN" string ::: I hope this makes sense :::

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this logically equivalent?

```
"...
(
    $drive AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_year' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$year')
    OR
    $fuel AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'vehicle_fuel' AND CAST($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '$fuel')
)
..."
```